# Unable to Install Sndfile with Amazon EC2 Instance due to unavailability

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, mlops

I am trying to deploy a flask application that uses TensorFlow and Librosa. So as a dependency of Librosa I need the **sndfile** package.

When I run my Flask app I get this error:

```
import librosa
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/

python3.7/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 211, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .audio import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 8, in <module>
    import soundfile as sf
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise OSError('sndfile library not found')
OSError: sndfile library not found
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-51 CE_Ayush_Deployment]$ python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from model_pipeline import Corona_Diagnoser
  File "/home/ec2-user/CE_Ayush_Deployment/model_pipeline.py", line 5, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 211, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .audio import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 8, in <module>
    import soundfile as sf
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise OSError('sndfile library not found')
OSError: sndfile library not found
```

I tried:

```
sudo yum install autoconf autogen automake build-essential libasound2-dev \
   libflac-dev libogg-dev libtool libvorbis-dev libopus-dev libmp3lame-dev \
   libmpg123-dev pkg-config python
```

I then get this message:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package build-essential available.
No package libasound2-dev available.
No package libflac-dev available.
No package libogg-dev available.
No package libvorbis-dev available.
No package libopus-dev available.
No package libmp3lame-dev available.
No package libmpg123-dev available.
No package pkg-config available.
```

I know the package is not available in the Amazon EC2 instance. Could anyone guide me on how to install the sndfile packages to the system?

Comment: Did you try `yum install libsndfile`?

Comment: Yes, the library is not found.

Comment: What OS flavour you have on this EC2 instance? Is it AL1, AL2, CentOS?

Comment: The OS flavour is Linux / UNIX

Comment: Linux has many different "version"? Ubuntu, amazon Linux 2, redhat, centos. What exactly are you using?

Comment: Amazon Linux (Inferred)

Comment: How about `libsndfile-dev`? Found it here: https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/148574.

Comment: Is it [Amazon Linux 2](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/) or the earlier [Amazon Linux AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/)? Here are [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#amazon-linux-image-id) on how to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install libsndfile and it's development files. Unfortunately it's not packaged up in a repository, but you can get it installed by downloading the RPMs directly

```
wget http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus/x86_64/RPMS.classic//libsndfile-1.0.31-alt1.x86_64.rpm
wget http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus/x86_64/RPMS.classic//libsndfile-devel-1.0.28-alt1.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum localinstall libsndfile-devel-1.0.31-alt1.x86_64.rpm
```

You can also install [libsndfile](https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile) from source.

Another option is to switch to Ubuntu, which has packages for `libsndfile` and `libsndfile-dev`. If you're looking to deploy tensorflow specifically then you should start with the [AWS Deep Learning AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/amis/). These AMIs are built by AWS and come with the drivers and a bunch of frameworks already installed. These AMis have Ubuntu flavored versions.

Comment: Still the error persists.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer. But I couldn't still resolveit.

Comment: Has the error changed at all?

Comment: If it doesn't help it shouldn't accepted as the answer :x @ogdenkev answer is much clearer, and helped me

Answer (score 2):

### Amazon Linux 2

I am on [Amazon Linux 2](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/), which you can verify by running the following on your EC2 server.

```sh
[ec2-user@fake-ip ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
```

The following packages are available from the [Amazon package repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#package-repository): `libsndfile-devel`, `libsndfile-utils`, `libsndfile`.

```
 [ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ yum search libsndfile
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
=============================================== N/S matched: libsndfile ================================================
libsndfile-devel.x86_64 : Development files for libsndfile
libsndfile-utils.x86_64 : Command Line Utilities for libsndfile
libsndfile.x86_64 : Library for reading and writing sound files
libsndfile.i686 : Library for reading and writing sound files
```

### Amazon Linux AMI

According to [Amazon Linux AMI package list](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages/), this earlier version of Amazon Linux does not have libsndfile. Although you can enable the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL), libsndfile does not appear to be there either.

```sh
[ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
[ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
... skipping lots of output
mirrorlist = https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
...
[ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ yum search libsndfile
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
epel/x86_64/metalink                         | 3.8 kB  00:00:00
epel                                         | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
(1/3): epel/x86_64/group_gz                  |  74 kB  00:00:00
(2/3): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                | 788 kB  00:00:00
(3/3): epel/x86_64/primary_db                | 6.1 MB  00:00:00
1067 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Warning: No matches found for: libsndfile
No matches found
```

The [libsndfile docs](https://libsndfile.github.io/libsndfile/) state that it has been compile on **Debian/GNU Linux**, but Amazon Linux AMI is not based on Debian. The build dependencies for libsndfile (`autoconf autogen automake build-essential libasound2-dev libflac-dev libogg-dev libtool libvorbis-dev libopus-dev libmp3lame-dev libmpg123-dev pkg-config python`)
all refer to Debian packages, which do not have the same name for other Linux flavors. In particular, `build-essential`, `libasound2-dev`, `libflac-dev`, `libopus-dev`, `libmp3lame-dev` and `libmpg123-dev` are not on EPEL.

```sh
[ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ yum search autoconf autogen automake build-essential \
    libasound2-dev   libflac-dev libogg-dev libtool libvorbis-dev libopus-dev \
    libmp3lame-dev   libmpg123-dev pkg-config python
... skipping output
Warning: No matches found for: build-essential
Warning: No matches found for: libasound2-dev
Warning: No matches found for: libflac-dev
Warning: No matches found for: libopus-dev
Warning: No matches found for: libmp3lame-dev
Warning: No matches found for: libmpg123-dev
```

`libmpelame-dev` may be `lame-devel`, `lame-libs`, `lame`, and/or `lame-mp3x`.

```
[ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ yum search lame
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1067 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
================================================== N/S matched: lame ===================================================
lame-devel.i686 : Development files for lame
lame-devel.x86_64 : Development files for lame
lame-libs.i686 : LAME MP3 encoding library
lame-libs.x86_64 : LAME MP3 encoding library
flamerobin.x86_64 : Graphical client for Firebird
lame.x86_64 : Free MP3 audio compressor
lame-mp3x.x86_64 : MP3 frame analyzer
```

`libflac-dev` may be `flac-devel`

```
[ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ yum search flac
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1067 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
================================================== N/S matched: flac ===================================================
flac-devel.x86_64 : Development libraries and header files from FLAC
easytag.x86_64 : Tag editor for mp3, ogg, flac and other music files
flac.i686 : An encoder/decoder for the Free Lossless Audio Codec
flac.x86_64 : An encoder/decoder for the Free Lossless Audio Codec
mp3fs.x86_64 : FUSE filesystem to transcode FLAC to MP3 on the fly
```

`libopus-dev` may be `opus-devel`

```
[ec2-user@fakeip ~]$ yum search opus
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1067 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
================================================== N/S matched: opus ===================================================
opus-devel.i686 : Development package for opus
opus-devel.x86_64 : Development package for opus
opus.i686 : An audio codec for use in low-delay speech and audio communication
opus.x86_64 : An audio codec for use in low-delay speech and audio communication
```

`libmpg123-dev` is https://www.mpg123.org/

### Recommendations

- Switch your EC2 to Amazon Linux 2 or Ubuntu
- Run your app in a Docker image on the EC2